No role is assigned in discord js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
Please tell me how to assign a role in discord.js by the user ID, which is located in the variable id (let id = interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[5].value;)
let id = interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[5].value;
await id.roles.add(config.defaultConfig.VERF_ROLE);              

doesn't work
Everything works if  id is taken from the member variable
const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);
await member.roles.add(config.defaultConfig.VERF_ROLE);


Here id is a string type. The roles property does not exist for the string type.
Instead, there is a way to get the GuildMember class from the id.
const id = interaction.message.embeds[0].fields[5].value;
const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(id);
await member.roles.add(config.defaultConfig.VERF_ROLE);

